# Azure web app for containers (Spring Boot 3 Java 17 using JDBC) connection issues w/ Microsoft SQL Server Hybrid Connection

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure-web-app-service, azure-hybrid-connections, spring-boot-3

### Overview

I have deployed a Spring Boot API from my private container registry to an Azure Web App for containers instance. I have setup a hybrid connection via Azure Hybrid Relay w/ a HCM hosted on a Windows 2022 server VM that has a connection to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

**Connection string:** jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>:<port>;databaseName=<db_name>

**Hybrid Connection:** <hostname>:<port>

When to container runs in the Web App on deployment, the run eventually errors out.

```
ERROR - Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Given the output logs, The container gets stuck on the HikariPool and no connection to the database is established.

```bash
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-08-31T11:20:16.250-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] Application      : Starting Application using Java 17.0.6 with PID 14128 
2023-08-31T11:20:16.252-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] Application      : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2023-08-31T11:20:17.085-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-31T11:20:17.110-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-08-31T11:20:17.656-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http)
2023-08-31T11:20:17.665-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-31T11:20:17.665-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-08-31T11:20:17.739-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-31T11:20:17.741-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1447 ms
2023-08-31T11:20:17.888-04:00  INFO 14128 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

The metric indicates that on the initial start up of the web application. The sender client connection fails

[Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqKlJ.png)

### Spring Boot Application Configuration

The azure deployment active profile uses managed Identity retrieves the database credentials from a specified azure keyvault (spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault)

***Note***: This configuration works in local testing using Intellij Azure Tools to replicate the managed identity

```yaml
server:
  port: 8000

spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      credential:
        managed-identity-enabled: true
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-source-enabled: true
          property-sources:
            - endpoint: https://${keyvault}.vault.azure.net/
              retry:
                mode: exponential
                exponential:
                  max-retries: 4
                  base-delay: PT0.0801S
                  max-delay: PT9S
  datasource:
    url: ${db-url}
    username: ${db-user}
    password: ${db-pass}
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

### HCM

All Configurations show a status of connected both in the HCM and in the Azure Portal

[HCM Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdp7y.png)

### Container Configuration

```yaml
FROM <java-17-image>

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PROFILE=<default_profile>

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ../../target/<application_name>.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE}", "app.jar"]
```

***Note*** Not running container as root user (excluded from example)

### Troubleshooting steps thus far

#### Test Managed Identity

I ran the application with the azure deployment active profile locally, utilizing Intellij Azure Tools. The configuration was able to access credentials from the keyvault and establish a connection to the database using the same connection string.

#### Check HCM Logs

I checked the event viewer on the Windows 2022 Server VM running the HCM to confirm there were no connection issues with it

[HCM Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw3Mr.png)

#### Establish Windows VM Host can reach the database

Made sure that the VM was able to access the database host

```
$ Test-NetConnection <host> -Port <port>
```

#### Check TCP connection in Web App Hudu Console

Made sure I can access to hybrid connection host from the Hudu bash console

```bash
$ tcpping <host> <port>
```

Comment: Did you try exposing PORT 80? Add `WEBSITES_PORT=80` in `Web App=>Settings=>Configuration=>Application Settings`.

Comment: @PravallikaKV yes I have WEBSITES_PORT=80 configured. I believe the problem with the container erroring out is due to the application not being able to establish a db connection through the hybrid connector. It tries establishing a connection using jdbc before starting on the specified port. So if that fails the port is exposed but nothing is running